# Inequality factor for similarity sensitive diversity

Tags: ecology, biodiversity

In a research article, Lou Jost has introduced the concept of inequality factor. The paper is "[The relation between evenness and diversity](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-2818/2/2/207/pdf)", published in 2010.  Inequality factor allows an intuitive interpretation of the slope of a diversity profile. It corresponds to "the number of maximally uneven communities" is very intuitive.

I could not find the analogue of inequality factors in context of similarity sensitive diversity, for instance, Leinster-Cobbold diversity. Is there any equivalent notion of inequality factor for the similarity sensitive case? Could anyone suggest me some readings?